# How to validate oidcToken from Google cloud task from within a Firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Like the title suggests, I am trying to validate a request to a Firebase onRequest function using an oidcToken from a Google cloud task. Other answers I've found here only explain how this works using GCP cloud functions and not directly with a Firebase function. Does this even require any special validation steps within the function, or is it handled automatically with the attached service account email?

Currently I schedule the task from within an onCall function. I attach a oidcToken from a service account I made specifically for tasks. Would it be sufficient to just attach my Firebase admin service account, or should I keep them separate?

I want this onRequest function to be locked down and only callable by internal operations like cloud tasks. Not regular authenticated Firebase users. Should I be using GCP cloud functions outside of Firebase for this?

To add context to what I am trying to achieve: I want a cloud task to remove a Firestore document after it expires. All resources from Google point to cloud tasks integration. If there is something better/easier to achieve this that would be awesome as well. I came across a Firebase solution called enqueue with onTaskDispatched from firebase-functions/v2/tasks, but can't find relevant docs for scheduling simple one-off scheduled tasks.

Comment: Firebase Function is Cloud Functions. The steps to verify an OIDC identity token are the same running inside the cloud or outside. A service account is not required to verify as RSA public keys are used. Notes: 1) How are you getting the ID token (HTTP Authorization header)? Google IAP removes the signature to prevent token replay. IAP also validates the token for you. If your goal is to extract details from the token, the format is published: base64 header + base64 payload + base64 signature. The payload is JSON and has the identity details. Edit your post to clarify your goal and problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply. As I am researching more, the purpose of this question seems to be shifting more towards how I should go about using Firebase enqueue `onTaskDispatched`. Seems like a solution geared more for Firebase users. I don't post on SO much. Should I still edit or just ask another question? I did mention enqueue at the bottom.

Comment: You have two different objectives/problems, so I would post separate questions. Focussed questions tend to get better answers.